# Bash script argument pass wrongly/wrong format means need to tell execution person please pass the correct format

Tags: bash

if I pass the second argument with double quotes it is working.
sh /tmp/tesh.sh status "ADC|DLM|MBS|ENDB"
status ADC
status DLM
status MBS
status ENDB

without double quotes it is not working so need to tell the execution person pass  the second argument with double-quotes how to write that logic

i am using below script how to validate the second argument format

Comment: valid=$1
a="$2"
POD_arg_1=$(echo a | tr "|" "\n")

for PODS in $POD_arg_1
do
    echo "$valid $PODS"
done
This script i m using

Comment: Your script does not know that there are no quotes. The problem is on the calling side. Without the quotes, the calling script tries to create a pipe and fails, and your script will never be invoked. Hence you can not detect this problem; this is the responsibility of the caller.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect malformed second argument using code like:

```
if ! [[ $2 =~ '|' ]]; then 
    echo 1>&2 "Error: malformed arg 2"
    exit 1
fi
```

or

```
case "$2" in
    *\|*) : ;;
    *)  echo 1>&2 "Error: malformed arg 2"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Both nicely done.

Comment: The semarics seem to be that arg2 is a list of items separated by `|`. So my code could fail when the list has only a single item. It is not clear if that is allowed (the question comment code would work fine (after fixing the bugs) with a list of size 1 - or even of size 0).